# weka.associations.fpgrowth: cannot handle any class attribute

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, data-mining, fpgrowth

i am getting this error in weka while converting my attributes from nominal to binary for FPGrowth. dataset contains all nominal values 14:06:56: weka.associations.fpgrowth: cannot handle any class attribute!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have a *class* attribute.

Association rule mining is for unlabeled data.

If you don't understand why exactly this error occurs, I suggest you check the source code of FpGrowth.